# Fatal error: Call to a member function sql_in_set() on a non-object in

Tags: php, phpbb3

My question is what exactly is this error message telling me? What do I need to do specifically?

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function sql_in_set() on a non-object in /home/savas/x/inc/recenttopicsfeed.php on line 15
```

I have a php page pulling users and info from a phpbb3 forum. I decided to add a recent topics side bar on the same page and use the code from elsewhere so it's not mine and I don't fully understand it. I get this error message.

I tried looking and can't figure it out, but so I guess I want to understand fully what this means to better try and solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: is you db connection ok?

Comment: My db connection is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error messages is explaining itself by saying that sql_in_set is being called on non object.

If you are familiar with OOPS concepts then you must know that whenever we are going to call some member functions of class, we have to do it through class objects.
e.g: $db=new Database();
$db->member_function();

In this example we are calling member_function by object $db of Database class.

As you have mentioned that you are using it phpbb3 form and copying code from somewhere else.

I suppose you are doing it something like:

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set('user_id', $sql_in);

as explained here: https://wiki.phpbb.com/Dbal.sql_in_set

So i suppose you are using it somewhere where $db is not accessible/not created  yet.

Try understanding the flow of phpbb3 and pass variables according to it.

Comment: That is a nice explanation, but it doesn't quite answer my question as you've pretty much read out the error message for me. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I was wondering what I must do next , specifically.

Anyway, I fixed it, I just had to rename $db to something else as that was being used by the script. So essentially it was getting confused. BUT I had changed it on the script and it didn't work so I tried changing it on my roster page and that was fine.